# Check condition in function.php

Tags: wordpress

I am using `woocommerce` plugin and I want to check condition that if a product has an **Upsale** then enqueue `script`.

Here is the `code` I am using :

```
    function ajax_add_to_cart_script() {
        global $product;
        if($product->get_upsells()):
      wp_enqueue_script( 'add-to-cart-variation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/frontend-custom.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
      wp_localize_script( 'add-to-cart-variation', 'AddToCartAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
      endif;
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_add_to_cart_script',99 );
```

But above code is giving me **Fatal error: Call to a member function get_upsells() on a non-object**.

Is this possible to achieve?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The global variable $product is defined only inside the loop. 
Probably you want to call that function with a product-related hook (say, woocommerce_single_product_summary, if you want the function to run in the area of the "add_to_cart" button in the single product page).